# Schema.org for weather forecast

Tags: schema.org, weather

I am currently developing a forecast weather webpage and I would like to use Schema.org to tag the weather forecast of a given place. Is that possible?

I have researched over [schema.org](https://schema.org/), but I haven't been able to find a type that could be compatible with the weather forecast properties such as:

- Weather
- Wind
- Humidity
- Degrees

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vocabulary Schema.org doesn’t offer specific types for describing the weather. You could always use the generic type [`Thing`](http://schema.org/Thing) (and sometimes maybe its sub-types [`Intangible`](http://schema.org/Intangible), [`Event`](http://schema.org/Event), and [`Action`](http://schema.org/Action)), but it would probably lack suitable properties to represent what you want to convey. [`StructuredValue`](http://schema.org/StructuredValue) (and some of its sub-types) might also be useful.

In the issue [Add vocab to support description of Weather](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/362) it gets discussed if/how to enable this with Schema.org.